# Headerstyle-horizontalalign is not working

Tags: asp.net

`ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"` is working fine for data cell column, but
`HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"` is not working for header of the `GridView`.

Why? How to resolve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The GridView headers are `<th>` elements. By default these are [centered and bold](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). So if you use a bootstrapper, pre-build skin etc, those usually set the text alignment of table headers to the left.

Now when you add `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"`, aspnet adds `align="center"` to the header row `<tr>`. But the subsequent `<th>` nodes have their alignment overwritten by the CSS.

What you can do is add a class to the header and overwrite the text alignment.

```
HeaderStyle-CssClass="centerHeaderText"

<style>
    .centerHeaderText th {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

If you use bootstrap you can simply use the class `text-center`

```
HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center"
```

Comment: What a great explanation.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a bootstrap website, `HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"` 
does not work.

The below code can be the solution:

```
HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-right"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Bootstrap and had this happen. I had to use the `text-center` class in Bootstrap.

`HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center"`